# line break formatting in IF/ELIF statement [Python3]

Tags: python

How would you format this code? I know there should be two line breaks before defining a function. Would you put another line break after `if new_requests_objectid > 0:` for readability? How about after `def assign_uniquekey_request():` or `assign_uniquekey_request()`?

Or maybe it's fine the way it is.

```
if new_requests_objectid > 0:
    # get last data object from Request table
    last_request = Popen(['curl',
                          '-H', 'application-id: %s' % backendless_appid,
                          '-H', 'secret-key: %s' % backendless_sk,
                          '-H', 'application-type: REST',
                          '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
                          '-X', 'GET',
                          '-v', 'https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Request/last'],
                         stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

    last_request_str = last_request.decode(encoding='utf-8')

    last_objectid = json.loads(last_request_str, strict=False)['objectId']

    # generate unique key for last entry in Request table
    uniquekey_request = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
                                for _ in range(6))


    # assign unique key to last entry in Request table
    def assign_uniquekey_request():
        Popen(['curl',
               '-H', 'application-id: %s' % backendless_appid,
               '-H', 'secret-key: %s' % backendless_sk,
               '-H', 'application-type: REST',
               '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json',
               '-X', 'PUT',
               '-d', '{\"requestId\":\"%s\"}' % uniquekey_request,
               '-v', 'https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Request/%s' % last_objectid])

    assign_uniquekey_request()
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I think that it is opinion of each person so it should be marked somehow...

Comment: Your indentation is off, but [no, there is no need to insert a new line after an `if` statement or function signature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines).

Comment: Well, first, you need to post a code sample that's actually correctly indented in the first place. Second, you have some wonky things going on here. Are you really defining that function inside your if statement? Does that function really only need to be defined conditionally? Also, why `elif` and not `else`? Why not just rewrite your `if` condition if you're only going to pass anyway?

Comment: The only readability change could be to place the function outside your if/elif statement. Otherwise, it's opinion.

Comment: Aah! Don't use cURL like that. If you _really_ want to use cURL, use [PycURL](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/). But I would **highly** recommend using [requests](http://python-requests.org/).

Comment: @fingaz - That's not just readability; it can affect the result of the code. However, I would agree that classes and functions should be defined unconditionally, and then called conditionally if necessary.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I was unsure if that was valid to say. Thank you for clarifying, I knew it didn't agree with me.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Fixed for indentation. Also changed `elif` to `else`. The `pass` was a placeholder but I think `else` works in my case. And you are right about defining the functions outside the statement. Noob here. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Cyphase Will definitely look into `requests`. I was using `curl` to capture response times and just used it for consistency. I will research to see if `requests` can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines):

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.
>
> Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a single blank line.
>
> Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).
>
> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.

Your code's newline formatting looks fine. See the sample below:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def actions(self):
        if 1:
            pass
        else:
            pass

        print(1)
        print(37)
        print(22)

        return
```

Note that newline rules are rigidly-defined and don't follow this guideline if you are working in the interactive interpreter, where you should only add an extra newline when you want the block you just finished writing to execute. The class above would need to be entered into the interpreter like this:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         pass
...     def actions(self):
...         if 1:
...             pass
...         else:
...             pass
...         print(1)
...         print(37)
...         print(22)
...         return
...
>>>
```